# Grammaticality in context

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

If someone asks about how much did you get or how many did you get about a total amount then will it be correct to say like this?:

> Now we know how many of how many tasks have been completed.
>
> How many lessons of the number of lessons you did?

and

> How much money of how much money did he get?
>
> How much money of the number of money did he get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - none of the example sentences you give are grammatical.

If you are speaking about a specific amount or total, and you have established what that is, then you can use the definite article to point to that amount, for example:

> How much of *the* money did you get?
>
> How many of *the* tasks did you complete?

*The* tasks would refer to a specific number of tasks which is your demoninator, the number that have been completed is your numerator.